# Force tableswitch instead of lookupswitch

Tags: java, scala, jvm, switch-statement, pattern-matching

Scala 2.11 compiles a `match` expression over a relatively dense `Int` range into a `lookupswitch`:

```
lookupswitch { // 21
    -12: 200
    -11: 200
    -10: 184
     -9: 190
     -8: 190
     -7: 190
     -6: 190
     -5: 190
     -4: 200
     -1: 200
      2: 195
      3: 195
      4: 195
      5: 195
      6: 184
      7: 184
     12: 184
     13: 184
     18: 184
     21: 184
     25: 184
default: 180
}
```

Whereas Java 7 compiles the equivalent `switch` statement into a `tableswitch`:

```
tableswitch { // -12 to 25
    -12: 168
    -11: 168
    -10: 177
     -9: 174
     -8: 174
     -7: 174
     -6: 174
     -5: 174
     -4: 168
     -3: 185
     -2: 185
     -1: 168
      0: 185
      1: 185
      2: 171
      3: 171
      4: 171
      5: 171
      6: 177
      7: 177
      8: 185
      9: 185
     10: 185
     11: 185
     12: 181
     13: 181
     14: 185
     15: 185
     16: 185
     17: 185
     18: 181
     19: 185
     20: 185
     21: 181
     22: 185
     23: 185
     24: 185
     25: 181
default: 185
}
```

Is there some way to force Scala into generating a `tableswitch` as well?

Comment: Why do you care? In my opinion, Scala's way is better since it produces smaller code. Performance-wise both variants are the same. JIT compiler will produce equally optimized code both for `lookupswitch` and `tableswitch`.

Comment: In fact, HotSpot JVM may compile `tableswitch` using a binary search and `lookupswitch` using a jump table, or vice versa. This depends on the number and the density of labels, but not on the bytecode itself.

Comment: @apangin [Official Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.10) state "Thus, a tableswitch instruction is probably more efficient than a lookupswitch where space considerations permit a choice." Is this outdated information? If you can provide an answer with generated native assembly or something to prove your point, I'd be happy to upvote and accept...

Comment: That statement still holds for interpreted execution or less optimizing JVMs in general. But that’s nothing to worry about, unless you run into performance problems which an objective tool like a profiler truly traces back to a switch instruction.

Comment: @apangin I agree it does not matter for performance, but Java's way is actually the "smaller" bytecode. This is counterintuitive because of the way `javap` prints out the switch, but `tableswitch` instruction ends up being 164-167 bytes (depending on alignment) and the `lookupswitch` is 176-179 bytes (depending on alignment). This is because `lookupswitch` needs to store each key as a 4-byte `int` while the key is implicit in `lookuptable`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**You should not care about the bytecode, since modern JVMs are smart enough to compile both `lookupswitch` and `tableswitch` in a similarly efficient way.**

Intuitively `tableswitch` should be faster, and this is also suggested by
[JVM specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.10):

> Thus, a tableswitch instruction is probably more efficient than a lookupswitch where space considerations permit a choice.

However, the spec was written 20+ years ago, when JVM had no JIT compiler. Is there a performance difference in a modern HotSpot JVM?

### The benchmark

```
package bench;

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.*;

@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class SwitchBench {
    @Param({"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"})
    int n;

    @Benchmark
    public long lookupSwitch() {
        return Switch.lookupSwitch(n);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public long tableSwitch() {
        return Switch.tableSwitch(n);
    }
}
```

To have precise control over the bytecode, I build `Switch` class with [Jasmin](https://github.com/Sable/jasmin).

```
.class public bench/Switch
.super java/lang/Object

.method public static lookupSwitch(I)I
    .limit stack 1

    iload_0
    lookupswitch
      1 : One
      2 : Two
      3 : Three
      4 : Four
      5 : Five
      6 : Six
      7 : Seven
      default : Other

One:
    bipush 11
    ireturn
Two:
    bipush 22
    ireturn
Three:
    bipush 33
    ireturn
Four:
    bipush 44
    ireturn
Five:
    bipush 55
    ireturn
Six:
    bipush 66
    ireturn
Seven:
    bipush 77
    ireturn
Other:
    bipush -1
    ireturn
.end method

.method public static tableSwitch(I)I
    .limit stack 1

    iload_0
    tableswitch 1
      One
      Two
      Three
      Four
      Five
      Six
      Seven
      default : Other

One: 
    bipush 11
    ireturn
Two:
    bipush 22
    ireturn
Three:
    bipush 33
    ireturn
Four:
    bipush 44
    ireturn
Five:
    bipush 55
    ireturn
Six:
    bipush 66
    ireturn
Seven:
    bipush 77
    ireturn
Other:
    bipush -1
    ireturn
.end method
```

The results show no performance difference between lookupswitch/tableswitch benchmarks, but there is a small variation depending on switch argument:

[image: lookupswitch vs. tableswitch performance]

### Assembly

Let's verify the theory by looking at generated assembly code.
The following JVM option will help: `-XX:CompileCommand=print,bench.Switch::*`

```
  # {method} {0x0000000017498a48} 'lookupSwitch' '(I)I' in 'bench/Switch'
  # parm0:    rdx       = int
  #           [sp+0x20]  (sp of caller)
  0x000000000329b240: sub    $0x18,%rsp
  0x000000000329b247: mov    %rbp,0x10(%rsp)    ;*synchronization entry
                                                ; - bench.Switch::lookupSwitch@-1

  0x000000000329b24c: cmp    $0x4,%edx
  0x000000000329b24f: je     0x000000000329b2a5
  0x000000000329b251: cmp    $0x4,%edx
  0x000000000329b254: jg     0x000000000329b281
  0x000000000329b256: cmp    $0x2,%edx
  0x000000000329b259: je     0x000000000329b27a
  0x000000000329b25b: cmp    $0x2,%edx
  0x000000000329b25e: jg     0x000000000329b273
  0x000000000329b260: cmp    $0x1,%edx
  0x000000000329b263: jne    0x000000000329b26c  ;*lookupswitch
                                                 ; - bench.Switch::lookupSwitch@1
  ...
```

What we see here is a binary search starting with a mid value 4 (this explains why case 4 has the best performance in the graph above).

But the interesting thing is that `tableSwitch` is compiled exactly the same way!

```
  # {method} {0x0000000017528b18} 'tableSwitch' '(I)I' in 'bench/Switch'
  # parm0:    rdx       = int
  #           [sp+0x20]  (sp of caller)
  0x000000000332c280: sub    $0x18,%rsp
  0x000000000332c287: mov    %rbp,0x10(%rsp)    ;*synchronization entry
                                                ; - bench.Switch::tableSwitch@-1

  0x000000000332c28c: cmp    $0x4,%edx
  0x000000000332c28f: je     0x000000000332c2e5
  0x000000000332c291: cmp    $0x4,%edx
  0x000000000332c294: jg     0x000000000332c2c1
  0x000000000332c296: cmp    $0x2,%edx
  0x000000000332c299: je     0x000000000332c2ba
  0x000000000332c29b: cmp    $0x2,%edx
  0x000000000332c29e: jg     0x000000000332c2b3
  0x000000000332c2a0: cmp    $0x1,%edx
  0x000000000332c2a3: jne    0x000000000332c2ac  ;*tableswitch
                                                 ; - bench.Switch::tableSwitch@1
  ...
```

### Jump table

But wait... Why binary search, not a jump table?

HotSpot JVM has an heuristics to generate a jump table only for switches with 10+ cases. This can be altered by the option `-XX:MinJumpTableSize=`.

OK, let's extend our test case with some more labels and check the generated code once again.

```
  # {method} {0x0000000017288a68} 'lookupSwitch' '(I)I' in 'bench/Switch'
  # parm0:    rdx       = int
  #           [sp+0x20]  (sp of caller)
  0x000000000307ecc0: sub    $0x18,%rsp         ;   {no_reloc}
  0x000000000307ecc7: mov    %rbp,0x10(%rsp)    ;*synchronization entry
                                                ; - bench.Switch::lookupSwitch@-1

  0x000000000307eccc: mov    %edx,%r10d
  0x000000000307eccf: dec    %r10d
  0x000000000307ecd2: cmp    $0xa,%r10d
  0x000000000307ecd6: jb     0x000000000307ece9
  0x000000000307ecd8: mov    $0xffffffff,%eax
  0x000000000307ecdd: add    $0x10,%rsp
  0x000000000307ece1: pop    %rbp
  0x000000000307ece2: test   %eax,-0x1faece8(%rip)        # 0x00000000010d0000
                                                ;   {poll_return}
  0x000000000307ece8: retq   
  0x000000000307ece9: movslq %edx,%r10
  0x000000000307ecec: movabs $0x307ec60,%r11    ;   {section_word}
  0x000000000307ecf6: jmpq   *-0x8(%r11,%r10,8)  ;*lookupswitch
                                                ; - bench.Switch::lookupSwitch@1
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Yes! Here is our computed jump instruction. Note, this is generated for `lookupswitch`. But there will be exactly the same one for `tableswitch`.

Amazingly, HotSpot JVM can generate jump tables even for switches with gaps and with outliers. `-XX:MaxJumpTableSparseness` controls how large the gaps can be. E.g. if there are labels from 1 to 10, then from 13 to 20 and the last label with the value 99 - JIT will generate a guard test for the value 99, and for the rest labels it will create a table.

### Source code

HotSpot source code will finally convince there should be no performance difference between [`lookupswitch`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/75d40493551f/src/share/vm/opto/parse2.cpp#l340) and [`tableswitch`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/75d40493551f/src/share/vm/opto/parse2.cpp#l290) after a method is JIT-compiled with C2. That's basically because the parsing of both instructions ends up with a call to the same [`jump_switch_ranges`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/75d40493551f/src/share/vm/opto/parse2.cpp#l497) function that works for an arbitrary set of labels.

### Conclusion

As we saw, HotSpot JVM may compile `tableswitch` using a binary search and `lookupswitch` using a jump table, or vice versa. This depends on the number and the density of labels, but not on the bytecode itself.

So, answering your original question - **you don't need to!**

Comment: Just came across your answer as it was used as "test" in some review ... awesome work. I hope my 25th vote here also results in a badge for this. Aweeeesome.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: You can check for creation of a table OR lookupswitch by annotating the match like so:

```
import scala.annotation.switch

(foo: @switch) match {
  case 0 =>
  case 1 =>
  //And so forth
}
```

If a given match is not possible to be compiled into a table OR lookupswitch, this will make it log a warning at compilation time.

Comment: "An annotation to be applied to a match expression. If present, the compiler will verify that the match has been compiled to **a tableswitch or lookupswitch** and issue an error if it instead compiles into a series of conditional expressions."